# Intellij Keymap Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, intellij-idea, keymapping

I'am trying to configure intellij IDE to use the same keymap as Xcode. But i cant find any Xcode keymap for IIDE (intellij IDE) - tried following [This Link](https://github.com/pitzcarraldo/IntelliJ-IDEA-Xcode-Keymap), but no luck. 
So i thought ok, why not just use Mac OSX 10.5+? Well this doesn't work as i thought either, e.g when i try to block comment (shift+/ och command /) it acts wierd. Also tried the "^R" for run - well here IIDE reacts to "control+r"...

Anybody out there having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode keymap exists only in AppCode and CLion products. [There is a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17142) to make it available for IntelliJ IDEA as well (and WebStorm).

You can try extracting the keymap from [CLion distribution](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download/), it can be found here `CLION_HOME\lib\resources.jar\keymaps\Xcode.xml`. Then you can place it into [idea.config.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`\keymaps` directory when IDE is not running.

Comment: Bummer! Is there any way one would get the keymap from AppCode to IIDE? Thanks for the update!

Comment: Tried to "steal" the CLion keymap. But it wont work for me in IJ. Anywasys - thanks for the help!